# Detect host OS with Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps

I've seen a number of posts asking about detecting the browser and os in Flutter apps which suggest plugins such as [client_information](https://pub.dev/packages/client_information) and [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus). However, what I haven't seen is how to detect these things all while running a Flutter web app.

My use-case is that I'd like to prompt the user to add my web app to their home screen. To do that I need to know their OS (don't want to prompt a macOS user to do this), and browser (Looks like this is a temporary requirement, as currently only safari can install web apps on the home screen so I need to direct them to open my app with Safari, but with iOS 16.4 launching soon third-party browsers will be able to do this as well).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `user agent` string, which contains information about the operating system and browser:

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;

void main() {
  String userAgent = html.window.navigator.userAgent;
  print(userAgent);
}
```

Output:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36
```

In addition, you can use [user_agent_parser](https://pub.dev/packages/user_agent_parser) to extract information from the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `defaultTargetPlatform` variable from the `flutter foundation` package.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            "You are running the web application on ${defaultTargetPlatform.name}",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```